# split list of strings using list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list `names` that contains **lists of strings**.

`names = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson Affiliate Peterson Acquaintance Dr. Rose', 'Vice president Dr. John Mister Schmid, PRT Miss Robertson, FDU']`

I want to **split each string** using `names_office` in a loop over `names`

`names_office = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Miss Robertson, FDU', 'Vice president Johnson', 'Affiliate Peterson', 'Acquaintance Dr. Rose', 'Vice president Dr. John', 'Mister Schmid, PRT']`

desired_output

`names = ['Acquaintance Muller', 'Vice president Johnson', 'Affiliate Peterson', 'Acquaintance Dr. Rose', 'Vice president Dr. John', 'Mister Schmid, PRT', 'Miss Robertson, FDU']`

I need to **iterate irrespective of order**.

Comment: What logic do you want to use to decide where one name ends and the next begins?  And where does this data come from?  If the original source of the data knows what the individual names are, you should fix the data at the source instead of trying to fix it after the fact.

Comment: Given that your desired output is just `names_office` in a different order, and  you don't care about the order, why not just do `names = names_office`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

re.findall("|".join(names_office), ",".join(names))
 
['Acquaintance Muller',
 'Vice president Johnson',
 'Affiliate Peterson',
 'Acquaintance Dr. Rose',
 'Vice president Dr. John',
 'Mister Schmid, PRT',
 'Miss Robertson, FDU']
```

The above will throw away values not found in the names_office list.

To maintain everything do:

```
results = []
pat = f"\\b({'|'.join(names_office)})\\b "
for i in names:
   results.extend(re.sub(pat, "\\1:",i).split(':'))

print(results)
```

Comment: actually, this results in `results = ['Mister', 'Schmid, PRT', 'Acquaintance', 'Muller']`

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand what you want to split by, but the following will split by `,` and flatten the results into a single list. Presumably you can adapt this to your use case, although I would be curious to understand the exact requirements, as I just couldn't figure it out from your question

```py
[part.strip()  for name in names for part in name.split(',')]
```

Comment: This clearly does not provide the output that OP is looking for.